# addEventListener ' load ' event isn't triggered

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

in my JS code an EventListener is not trigger when i load my webpage. what could be the problem?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    evaluate = 0;

    if (firstD.checked) {
        evaluate++
    }
    if (secondD.checked) {
        evaluate++
    }
    if (thirdD.checked) {
        evaluate++



    }


})
```

https://codepen.io/haluk-mit-boray/pen/OJbbzLd

Comment: How do you know it's not triggered? Your handler function doesn't log anything or call any other function.

Comment: Create a snippet or a pen with the full code please

Comment: @Lennholm i control with debbuing. the code is skipping this event.

Comment: @cri_pava i added codepen of all JS

Comment: I'm not sure what you are triyng to do but,as far as i know, the only way that a radio button is checked right after a page is loaded is when the attribute checkeddefault is set in the HTML. So i think you should use a different approach like an event listener on "click" or "change"

Comment: @cri_pava actually i have 37 y/n questions i would like to write all answers to SQL DB then i will get pre-saved answer from sql and run js code again when page is loaded to calculate value of progressbars

Comment: @Mythran Seems to be triggered as expected to me. I placed a `console.log()` in the handler function in your codepen and it does indeed log to the console.

Comment: @Mythran if you are saving the answer in DB you could just made a check from there instead then looking for the cecked butons

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick example on usage, hope it helps as reference, or maybe you can add more context to where is your code embedded

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function() {
          console.log("Your functionality");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Body</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can find more documentatio here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: this is not the problem